# shared github codevelopment (only 2 users) creates unresolvable push/pull conflicts

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, multi-user

We are trying to use github, but we seem to be using it spectacularly wrong. I created a repository with raw data files, source code, processed data files, results files (like png and html and csv files). As long as I was the only person using it, all was well. However, I've granted access to a collaborator, and now she and I are completely unable to pull or push from the repository. It seems that the creation of processed data files is creating incompatibilities that make data pull/push impossible for both of us. Indeed, we have to delete all new work in order to fetch, which makes github impractical for its intended purpose, which is codevelopment of code (and results and figures, etc.)

We are at an impasse. The current workarounds are all supremely suboptimal:
a) to operate under the notion that github is a single-user paradigm 
b) to use git hub for file passing but not involve it with active development, so it becomes a complicated dropbox.

I *think* the best strategy is to delete all but a the barest-of-bones source files and maybe the original untouchable raw data source file. Less is more. (Nothing is best?) But even deleting files from an active repository is not apparently supported. That is, I can add files to a .gitignore. I can delete them from my local image. But I have to pull before I push, and they all show up again. Rebasing isn't the answer.

Is there some way to "push" a file-delete event? Or delete all but 3 or 4 files from the github.com account? Or should I just delete the whole repository and start over? Or should I go back to svn, which had no problem layering png files, etc., and only declared a conflict when there was one in a source file?

Is there some way to teach github to merge only those files that should be sensibly merge-able, like files with suffixes .R, .h, .c, .cpp, .py, .javac, .html, etc. and simply layer-over the other files with appropriate version number increments, like in svn?

Efforts to find answers to these questions in documentation and on-line only perpetuate the frustration.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: There are suggestions to use "git  rm -- cached *.png" followed by "git commit --amend -CHEAD" results in the error "You are in the middle of a merge -- cannot amend"  which may be true, but it leaves me nowhere.

Comment: One thing that I would do, as mentioned above, is not commit the generated artifacts - I would add a CI/CD hook that would generate them and create the artifacts independent of individuals machines.  One thing that you could also do is set the git attribute for any non-merge files to be binary - then it would not try complex merges.

Comment: Thank you, Cinderhaze. Setting a git attribute to binary seems like the thing to do. I am surprised that this is a "customizing" feature (not an introductory one) as I imagine most users would face this problem within a day of starting to use git. Or, within a day of using git for co-development. It is the second user that breaks the well-managed-repository design. Imagine the knots that form when a 3rd user joins, and then no one can push-or-pull anything!

Comment: I will post a new question which addresses just this last point. Working with a single source file, my collaborator and I have been able to create absolute stasis. All committing/all pushing/all pulling is blocked, even after we resolved the merged parts of the code and the code runs fine. What a nightmare git is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, Git (and repositories in GitHub) should be used for source code, not for *generated* files (your "result files").
"original untouchable raw data source file." might be versioned as well if they are immutable.

If you need to add generated files (that are likely to change each time you commit new source code, and will generate conflicts), you might consider, in order to memorize said files, to:

- make an archive (zip, tar, ...) of all those non source files
- [add it as a "release"](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-releases-in-a-repository) associated to your commit

But that seems cumbersome to do for *every* commit though.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I needed to hear. subversion had no problem with this. It is now not clear to me why the world prefers git with this more-than-a-little-broken design concept to svn.